# IIS 8.5: A process serving application pool '<ApplicationPoolName>' suffered a fatal communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, was, stateserver, web-garden

I am running an ASP.NET MVC application on IIS 8.5.9600.16384 under Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard.
Sometimes I get below error in the event log that makes my application not responding for a while.

Event ID 5011 - Source: WAS

> A process serving application pool '' suffered a
> fatal communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service. The process id was '1668'. The data field contains the error number.

My website uses Web Garden and its application pool is set to 4 worker processes and using mode StateServer. Also application pool identity is set to a domain account.

ASP.NET State service runs in the same machine where my site is published.

Any ideas about what could be the problem?

Comment: The WAS could stop if the application pool gets crashed frequently. The 5011 event should contain the application pool name.please check your event error detail which dll it causes for the issue. you could use the Debug Diagnostics tool to troubleshoot the issue. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc735271(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: @JalpaPanchal So... does it mean that if I have some application pools (a different pool per web site) and one of them crashes the WAS service stops? so then the other independent application pool stop working as well as they all depend on WAS as well. So all the other applications would stop? As far as I know, if an application pool crashes, it does not affect to the others but in this case since there is one WAS service in the system, all them will be affected?

Comment: as mentioned in the document IIS application pools in turn depend on the Windows Process Activation Service (WAS). If WAS is not running or errors occur during the startup or shutdown of an application pool, Web sites and Web applications may not be available. so make sure the application pool is running and try to use the  Debug Diagnostics tool to troubleshoot the issue.